# Why can I execute this query but not see its execution plan?

Tags: oracle, explain

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT table_name,
  to_number(extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '
  ||owner
  ||'.'
  ||table_name)),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) AS COUNT
FROM all_tables
WHERE UPPER(owner) = UPPER('my_schema');
```

This query runs just fine and displays output. But doing EXPLAIN on this query produces:

> ORA-01039: insufficient privileges on underlying objects of the view

As per the Oracle documentation:

> You must have the privileges necessary to execute the SQL
>   statement for which you are determining the execution plan. If the SQL statement accesses a view, then you must have privileges to access any tables and views on which the view is based.
>
> To examine the execution plan produced by an EXPLAIN PLAN statement,
>   you must have the privileges necessary to query the output table.

1. I do have privileges on the table accessed by SQL as the query runs fine.
2. By output table I assume it means `dbms_xplan.display` which is to store calculated plan. I think that I have privilege on that aswell as following runs fine:

> ```
> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable;
> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);
> ```

**What's missing here?**

Answer (score 3):

> I do have privileges on the table accessed by SQL as the query runs
>   fine.

And that is a false assumption. Just because you can query a view, it doesn't necessarily mean you have privileges on the underlying tables. Anyone can query the view `ALL_TABLES`, but a regular user doesn't have the privileges to query the underlying tables such as `OBJ$` or `TAB$`.

This is how it works, and it is really easy to reproduce. Create two users, one with a table and view, then grant `SELECT` on that view to another user:

```
SQL> grant create session, create table, create view to u1 identified by u1;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create session to u2 identified by u2;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> create table u1.t1(id number);

Table created.

SQL> create view u1.v1 as select * from u1.t1;

View created.

SQL> grant select on u1.v1 to u2;

Grant succeeded.
```

Now connect as u2, and try to select from the view:

```
SQL> connect u2/u2
Connected.

SQL> select * from u1.v1;

no rows selected
```

No problem. Now try to explain:

```
SQL> explain plan for select * from u1.v1;
explain plan for select * from u1.v1
                                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01039: insufficient privileges on underlying objects of the view
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Oracle documentation it says that you mist have an `EXPLAIN_PLAN` table to store the information:

> Before issuing an EXPLAIN PLAN statement, you must have a table to hold its output. PLAN_TABLE is the default sample output table into which the EXPLAIN PLAN statement inserts rows describing execution plans. Use the SQL script UTLXPLAN.SQL to create the PLAN_TABLE in your schema. The exact name and location of this script depends on your operating system. On Unix, it is located in the $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin directory.

Run this script and you will be able to use the `EXPLAIN PLAN`.

Comment: Do you mean `dbms_xplan.display`? Apparently I have it already as other EXPLAIN statements are running just fine.

Comment: I have always used the default table. Never this `dbms_xplan.display`. Do you have rights to this object (guess so since you say that other `EXPLAIN PLAN` statements work)? The error should not come from your `select count(*)` statement since `all_tables` only returns tables where you have access to (unless you lack the `select` privilege).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the UPDATE privilege on the underlying tables. As I pointed out on stackoverflow, the SELECT privilege may not be enough

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74706625/12884507

Comment: Clearly there's no UPDATE involved in the OP's query.